# how to insert text to QLineEdit Using keyboard onScreen

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, keyboard, pyqt5

I'm making a Login GUI program using PyQt5 on python which is in this program I create a keyboard on this layout. my problem is, I cannot insert text on QLineEdit using the keyboard what I have done. what should I do to fix it?

this is my first program on pyqt, I have no idea to fix it.

# x <-- 3

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self, x):                                        
        super().__init__()
        self.L_ID = QLabel("User ID :",self)
        self.L_ID.setFont(QFont('Arial', 16))
        self.L_ID.move(25, 25)

        self.entry_ID = QLineEdit(self)
        self.entry_ID.move(130, 20)
        self.entry_ID.resize(450,40)

        self.L_Pass = QLabel("Pass :",self)
        self.L_Pass.setFont(QFont('Arial', 16))
        self.L_Pass.move(25, 85)

        self.entry_Pass = QLineEdit(self)
        self.entry_Pass.move(130, 80)
        self.entry_Pass.resize(450,40)

        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.lay = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)

        names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm','Del',
                 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z','Shift',
                 '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '.', "'",'Enter']

        positions = [(i + 1, j) for i in range(3) for j in range(13)]

        x = 100
        d = 100
        i=0
        j=135
        for name in names:
            self.pushButton = QPushButton(name, self)
            if(name == 'Enter'):
                self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(int("{}".format(d)), j, 85, 35))
            else:
                self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(int("{}".format(d)), j, 40, 35))
            self.pushButton.setText(name)
            text = self.pushButton.text()
            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda ch, text=text : print("{}".format(text)))
            #self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton_{}".format(str(i).zfill(2)))
            i += 1
            d += 43
            if(i == 14):
                j +=45
                x = 100
                d = 100
                i=0

        #self.numButton = 4

        pybutton = QPushButton('Space', self)
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)
        pybutton.setGeometry(QRect(350, j+45, 100, 35))

        #self.lay.addWidget(pybutton)
        #self.lay.addStretch(1)

    def clickMethod(self):
        newBtn = QPushButton('New Button{}'.format(self.numButton), self)
        self.numButton += 1
        newBtn.clicked.connect(lambda : print("\nclicked===>> {}".format(newBtn.text())))
        self.lay.addWidget(newBtn)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow(3)
    mainWin.setGeometry(50, 50, 800, 480)
    mainWin.setFixedSize(800, 480) # 3 --> x
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

I can show the text of my button to the shell, but not on QLineEdit. how to insert text to QLineEdit using my onscreen keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a generic solution it is best to send [`QKeyEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html) to the widget that has the focus (you have to remove the focus on the buttons) using [`QCoreApplication::postEvent(...)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent).

To make the logic simple we create a dictionary that associates each text with a [`Qt::Key`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyevent.html#key).

For special cases such as <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> the text must be modified.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

LETTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
NUMBERS = "1234567890"
LUT = {
    "a": QtCore.Qt.Key_A,
    "b": QtCore.Qt.Key_B,
    "c": QtCore.Qt.Key_C,
    "d": QtCore.Qt.Key_D,
    "e": QtCore.Qt.Key_E,
    "f": QtCore.Qt.Key_F,
    "g": QtCore.Qt.Key_G,
    "h": QtCore.Qt.Key_H,
    "i": QtCore.Qt.Key_I,
    "j": QtCore.Qt.Key_J,
    "k": QtCore.Qt.Key_K,
    "l": QtCore.Qt.Key_L,
    "m": QtCore.Qt.Key_M,
    "n": QtCore.Qt.Key_N,
    "o": QtCore.Qt.Key_O,
    "p": QtCore.Qt.Key_P,
    "q": QtCore.Qt.Key_Q,
    "r": QtCore.Qt.Key_R,
    "s": QtCore.Qt.Key_S,
    "t": QtCore.Qt.Key_T,
    "u": QtCore.Qt.Key_U,
    "v": QtCore.Qt.Key_V,
    "w": QtCore.Qt.Key_W,
    "x": QtCore.Qt.Key_X,
    "y": QtCore.Qt.Key_Y,
    "z": QtCore.Qt.Key_Z,
    "Del": QtCore.Qt.Key_Delete,
    "Shift": QtCore.Qt.Key_Shift,
    "Enter": QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter,
    "Space": QtCore.Qt.Key_Space,
    "1": QtCore.Qt.Key_1,
    "2": QtCore.Qt.Key_2,
    "3": QtCore.Qt.Key_3,
    "4": QtCore.Qt.Key_4,
    "5": QtCore.Qt.Key_5,
    "6": QtCore.Qt.Key_6,
    "7": QtCore.Qt.Key_7,
    "8": QtCore.Qt.Key_8,
    "9": QtCore.Qt.Key_9,
    "0": QtCore.Qt.Key_0,
    ".": QtCore.Qt.Key_Period,
    "'": QtCore.Qt.Key_Apostrophe,
}


class KeyBoard(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        letters = LETTERS[: len(LETTERS) // 2], LETTERS[len(LETTERS) // 2 :]
        numbers = NUMBERS + ".'"

        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(*letters)):
            for j, letter in enumerate((a, b)):
                button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(
                    text=letter,
                    clicked=self.onClicked,
                    focusPolicy=QtCore.Qt.NoFocus,
                )
                button.setFixedSize(40, 35)
                grid_layout.addWidget(button, j, i)

        for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
            button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(
                text=number,
                clicked=self.onClicked,
                focusPolicy=QtCore.Qt.NoFocus,
            )
            button.setFixedSize(40, 35)
            grid_layout.addWidget(button, 2, i)

        for i, text in enumerate(("Del", "Shift")):
            button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(
                text=text, clicked=self.onClicked, focusPolicy=QtCore.Qt.NoFocus
            )
            button.setFixedSize(40, 35)
            grid_layout.addWidget(button, i, 13)

        button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(
            text="Enter", clicked=self.onClicked, focusPolicy=QtCore.Qt.NoFocus
        )
        button.setFixedSize(85, 35)
        grid_layout.addWidget(button, 2, 12, 1, 2)

        button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(
            text="Space", clicked=self.onClicked, focusPolicy=QtCore.Qt.NoFocus
        )
        button.setFixedSize(100, 35)
        grid_layout.addWidget(
            button, 3, 0, 1, 13, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
        )
        self.setFixedSize(self.sizeHint())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onClicked(self):
        button = self.sender()
        if button is None:
            return
        widget = QtWidgets.QApplication.focusWidget()

        text = button.text()
        key = LUT[text]
        if text in ("Del", "Shift", "Enter", "Space"):
            if text in ("Shift", "Enter"):
                text = ""
            elif text == "Space":
                text = " "
            elif text == "Del":
                text = chr(0x7F)
        event = QtGui.QKeyEvent(
            QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress, key, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier, text
        )
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.postEvent(widget, event)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        font = QtGui.QFont("Arial", 16)

        user_id_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("User ID:", font=font)
        user_id_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(font=font)

        pass_id_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Pass:", font=font)
        pass_id_lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(font=font)

        keyboard = KeyBoard()

        flay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(central_widget)
        flay.addRow(user_id_label, user_id_lineedit)
        flay.addRow(pass_id_label, pass_id_lineedit)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(keyboard, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        flay.addRow(lay)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thank you for your reply sir. your code was awesome. i will try to understand this code. Thank you.

Comment: if i create multiple menu on one scripts, that's code will stilll work?
for example first page is Login, next i will go to registration page.

Comment: do you have some sugestion for me, to create multiple menu and using this keyboard program?

Comment: @YogiJanuardi Have you already created the pages ?, I understand the page widgets that occupy the same space but not at the same time, if that is what you mean you must use QStackedLayout or QStackedWidget to implement that logic. If you have never used Qt you will have to invest time in trying the basics, review the thousands of examples that exist on the Internet about PyQt5

Comment: yes,i have script with multiple pages. this is can move from one page to another pages. but i was confused to add and edit your keyboard code to my script.

Comment: @YogiJanuardi You have to restructure your code, in the main window you must have a vertical layout, in the upper part there must be the QStackeWidget / QStackedLayout, and in the lower part the KeyBoard. In the QStackeWidget / QStackedLayout you must place each page

Comment: i i try post my code in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733505/how-to-create-multiple-pages-and-keyboard-on-each-pages . if you have a time, maybe can look at this link, sir. Thankyou sir.